# JTA Transaction Scope

Tags: spring, hibernate, jta, message-listener

I am using JTA transaction manager in a spring message listener application. The Database interface is maintained in a seperate project and added as dependency to the listener and the class is annotated with Transactional and the context file in the dependent project is configured with jta transaction manager bean definition.

In this case what will be the scope of transaction, for example if there is a delay in the listener will it come under the scope of transaction since the context is not imported to the main listener project? Also how do the transaction time out works, Is it applicable only for classes annotated with @Transactional or if there is any delay in other methods outside of this class, do jta manage this?